# Is it possible to set any attributes (such as a class) of the `a` tag when using `getLink()`?

Tags: templating, link

This code:

```
{{ foo.getLink() }}
```

Outputs this:

```
<a href="URL_HERE">NAME_OF_PAGE</a>
```

What I really want is something like:

```
<a href="URL_HERE" class="bar">NAME_OF_PAGE</a>
```

Is it possible to set "class" and/or other html attributes when using Craft CMS Entry Property [getLink()](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getLink)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `getLink` outputs a very simple version of the link.

If you want something more complex, you'll need to build it manually...

```
<a href="{{ foo.url }}" class="bar">{{ foo.title }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try LinkIt. Allows you to set attributes.
https://github.com/fruitstudios/LinkIt/blob/master/README.md